# How do I fix this broken JS ERB?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I am rendering a group of categories on my `home#index` page like so:

`views/home/index.html.erb`

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="video-list">
    <%= render "home/categories" %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is what my `home/_categories.html.erb` looks like:

```
<div class="list-section" id="categories">
  <% @filter.each do |category| %>
    <%= render partial: "categories/category", locals: { category: category } %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

This is my `categories/_category.html.erb`:

```
<h3 class="video-list-title"><%= category %></h3>
<div class="video-list-carousel-con scroll">
  <div class="items">
    <% Program.tagged_with(category).each do |program| %>
      <div class="video-list-thumbnail-con">
        <%= image_tag program.header_image_url %>
        <div class="thumbnail-overlay">
          <span>Plus Icon</span>
          <span>i Icon</span>
        </div>
        <p><strong><%= program.name %></strong></p>
        <p><%= program.airs_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is my `HomeController#Index`:

```
  def index
    @all_tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.map(&:name)
    if params["search"]
      @filter = params["search"]["categories"].flatten.reject(&:blank?)
      @programs = Program.all.global_search("#{@filter}")
      @recommendations = @filter.empty? ? Program.all : Program.all.tagged_with(@filter, any: true)
    else
      @filter = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.map(&:name)
      @recommendations = Program.all
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

This is my search form in my `_navbar.html.erb` partial:

```
 <%= simple_form_for :search, url: root_path, method: "GET" do |f| %>
     <%= f.input :categories, label: "Category", collection: @all_tags, as: :check_boxes %>
     <%= f.submit "Search", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
     <%= link_to "Reset", root_path %>
  <% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".form-check-input");
  var form = document.querySelector('form');

  for (const check of checkBoxes) {
  check.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    console.log('checked');
    Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
  });
  }
</script>
```

So all of the above works for normal form submissions.

However, I am trying to `ajaxify` the entire thing. I add `remote: true` to my form and I created the following `index.js.erb`, but it isn't working:

```
function replacePrograms (innerHTML) {
  const categories = document.getElementById('categories');
  categories.innerHTML = innerHTML;
}

if ('<%= @filter %>' === "[]") {
  replacePrograms("<%= j render 'home/categories', categories: Program.all %>");
}
else {
  replacePrograms("<%= j render 'home/categories', categories: @filter %>");
}
```

What I want to happen is when I click on any of the checkboxes, it refreshes the entire collection of categories on my `home/_categories.html.erb`.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Firs comment: You should use "replaceWith()" instead of "innerHTML=" because the DOM element is duplicated after refresh

Comment: I don't understand `categories: Program.all`, because it actually is not "category" bu "programs"

Comment: What can you see in the navigator inspector? What is the content of the response?

Comment: @Jean-MichelGigault yeah I have to clean it up a bit....I actually fixed this issue. But I know it has other issues that I still need to work through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that I wasn't actually selecting the form & checkboxes properly in my JS.

So I replaced:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll(".form-check-input");
  var form = document.querySelector('form');

  for (const check of checkBoxes) {
  check.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    console.log('checked');
    Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
  });
  }
</script>
```

With:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var checkBoxes = document.querySelectorAll("div.filters input.check_boxes");
  var form = document.querySelector('div.filters form.simple_form.search');

  for (const check of checkBoxes) {
  check.addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    Rails.fire(form, 'submit');
  });
  }
</script>
```

And now it works.

It now has other issues, but I will work through those.